# OrientDB hangs when creating edge with useLightweightEdges enabled

Tags: c#, orientdb

I'm new to OrientDb (and noSQL databases in general) and have put together a small application to model "friend" relationships using the [OrientDB.NETStandard-1.5 nuget package](https://github.com/orientechnologies/OrientDB-NET.binary).

The "FriendOf" edge is ideally just a link between two Person vertices, I had read on the [OrientDb documentation](https://orientdb.org/docs//3.0.x/java/Lightweight-Edges.html) that the use of lightweight edges may increase performance. The below code works fine when lightweight edges are disabled. However, when enabling them the line to create the edge hangs.

Am I missing something?

```
public static void EnableLightweightEdges(ODatabase orient)
{
   orient.Command("ALTER DATABASE custom useLightweightEdges=true");
}

public static void DisableLightweightEdges(ODatabase orient)
{
   orient.Command("ALTER DATABASE custom useLightweightEdges=false");
}

public ODatabase Connect()
{
   return new ODatabase(_connectionOptions);
}

public void EnsureCreated()
{
   using (var orient = Connect())
   {
       DisableLightweightEdges(orient);
       if (!orient.Schema.IsClassExist<Person>())
       {
           orient.Create.Class<Person>().Extends<OVertex>().CreateProperties().Run();
       }

       if (!orient.Schema.IsClassExist("FriendOf"))
       {
           orient.Create.Class("FriendOf").Extends<OEdge>().Run();
       }
       CreatePeople(orient);
   }
}

private static void CreatePeople(ODatabase orient)
{         
   // Clear existing data
   orient.Delete.Edge("FriendOf").Run();
   orient.Delete.Vertex<Person>().Run();

   var person1 = new Person {Id = Guid.Parse("199a5b7a-b4fe-4927-901b-d5b5d2226045"), Name = "Person1"};
   var person1Vertex = orient.Create.Vertex(person1).Run();

   var person2 = new Person {Id = Guid.Parse("5dee19d8-86f0-41a8-b2d8-62a77f80b6d1"), Name = "Person2"};
   var person2Vertex = orient.Create.Vertex(person2).Run();

   orient.Create.Edge("FriendOf").From(person1.ORID).To(person2.ORID).Run();
}
```

Comment: FWIW I raised the same issue on their github https://github.com/orientechnologies/OrientDB-NET.binary/issues/166